# Add a (copied) value to duplicated row in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I would like to copy a rows value in case it's duplicated in another column.

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   pat_id   Dup DD   
 1      1     1 TRUE 
 2      2     1 NA   
 3      3     3 FALSE
 4      4     4 NA   
 5      5     5 TRUE 
 6      6     5 NA   
 7      7     7 FALSE
 8      8     7 NA   
 9      9     9 FALSE
10     10    10 TRUE 

sample <- data.frame(pat_id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
                     Dup = c(1,1,3,4,5,5,7,7,9,10),
                     DD = c("TRUE", "NA","FALSE", "NA", "TRUE", "NA","FALSE","NA","FALSE","TRUE"))
```

Column Dup has duplicates. Column DD shows TRUE/FALSE for one of these, it also has a lot of NA values. If Dup is duplicated, i would like the column DD to show the same value. If there is no duplicate and DD shows NA, it should become FALSE.
I would like to get the following output.

```
   pat_id   Dup DD       DDx
 1      1     1 TRUE     TRUE
 2      2     1 NA       TRUE
 3      3     3 FALSE    FALSE
 4      4     4 NA       FALSE
 5      5     5 TRUE     TRUE
 6      6     5 NA       TRUE
 7      7     7 FALSE    FALSE
 8      8     7 NA       FALSE
 9      9     9 FALSE    FALSE
10     10    10 TRUE     TRUE
```

Ive tried it with the duplicated function, but this does not allow me to copy another columns value to the duplicated row.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible way. First `group_by` `Dup`, if `any` `DD` is `TRUE` then `xDD` should be `TRUE`. Now we have to get rid of the `NA` values with `ifelse`. If the new column is `NA` then it should be `FALSE` otherwise it should be the value it is.

```r
library(dplyr)

sample <- data.frame(pat_id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
                     Dup = c(1,1,3,4,5,5,7,7,9,10),
                     DD = c("TRUE", "NA","FALSE", "NA", "TRUE", "NA","FALSE","NA","FALSE","TRUE"))

sample %>%
  group_by(Dup) %>% 
  mutate(xDD = any(as.logical(DD)) %>% ifelse(is.na(.), FALSE, .))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   Dup [7]
#>    pat_id   Dup DD    xDD  
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <lgl>
#>  1      1     1 TRUE  TRUE 
#>  2      2     1 NA    TRUE 
#>  3      3     3 FALSE FALSE
#>  4      4     4 NA    FALSE
#>  5      5     5 TRUE  TRUE 
#>  6      6     5 NA    TRUE 
#>  7      7     7 FALSE FALSE
#>  8      8     7 NA    FALSE
#>  9      9     9 FALSE FALSE
#> 10     10    10 TRUE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>